# Retrieve different values in order if empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with different type of measures, using a `id_measure_type` for identifiying them. I need to do a SELECT in which I retrieve measures all summed for that period and each unit (`id_unit`) butif some measure is empty retrieve another one and so.

The measures are per date, unit and hour. This is a summary of my table:

```
id_unit     dateBid     hour    id_measure_type     measure
252         05/22/2013  11      6                   500
252         05/22/2013  11      4                   250
252         05/22/2013  11      1                   300
107         05/22/2013  11      4                   773
107         05/22/2013  11      1                   500
24          05/22/2013  11      6                   0
24          05/22/2013  11      4                   549
24          05/22/2013  11      1                   150
```

I need a select that make a `SUM` for all the input data range and gets the "best" measure type in this order: First the `id_measure_type = 6`, and if its **empty or 0** then the `id_measure_type = 4`, and by the same condition, then the `id_measure_type = 1`, and if nothing then 0.

This select is correct as long as there is every measure for type 6:

```
SELECT id_unit, SUM(measure) AS measure
FROM UNIT_MEASURES
WHERE dateBid BETWEEN '03/23/2013' AND '03/24/2013' AND id_unit IN (325, 326) 
AND id_measure_type = 6 GROUP BY id_unit
```

The inputs are the range of dates and the units. There is a way to do it in one single select?

**EDIT:**
I also have a `calendar` table that contains every date and hour so it can be used to do joins with it (to retrieve every single hour) if necessary.

**EDIT:**
The values are never going to be `NULL`, when "empty or 0" I mean values that are 0 or are missing for a hour. I need that every possible hour is in the SUM, from the "best" possible type of measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16688820/1967056) works perfectly, but since there is a lot of data in the table, it last for more than 3 minutes to do the select.

I made my own solution, wich is larger and uglier, but sightly faster (it last about 1 second):

```
SELECT tUND.id_unit, ROUND(SUM(
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(t1.measure, 0) > 0 THEN t1.measure ELSE 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(t2.measure, 0) > 0 THEN t2.measure ELSE
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(t3.measure, 0) > 0 THEN t3.measure ELSE 0 
    END END END END
/1000),3) AS myMeasure
FROM calendar
LEFT OUTER JOIN UNITS_TABLE tUND ON tUND.id_unit IN (252, 107)
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEASURES_TABLE t1 ON t1.id_measure_type = 6 
    AND t1.dateBid = dt AND t1.hour = h AND t1.id_uf = tUND.id_uf
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEASURES_TABLE t2 ON t2.id_unit = t1.id_unit 
    AND t2.dateBid = t1.dateBid AND t2.id_measure_type = 1 
    AND t2.id_unit = tUND.id_unit 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEASURES_TABLE t3 ON tCNT.id_unit = tUFI.id_unit
    AND t3.dateBid = t1.dateBid AND t3.id_measure_type = 4 
    AND t3.id_unit = tUND.id_unit 
WHERE dt BETWEEN '03/23/2013' AND '03/24/2013' 
GROUP BY tUND.id_unit
```

Answer (score 1):

Not certain I understand you correctly but I think this should work (change to your table)

Setup for my test:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ([id_unit] INT, [dateBid] DATE, [hour] INT, [id_measure_type] INT, [measure] INT);

INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT *
      FROM (
        VALUES (252, GETDATE(), 11, 6, 500)
             , (252, GETDATE(), 11, 4, 250)
             , (252, GETDATE(), 11, 1, 300)
             , (107, GETDATE(), 11, 4, 773)
             , (107, GETDATE(), 11, 1, 500)
         ) [Values]([id_unit], [dateBid], [hour], [id_measure_type], [measure]);
```

Actual Query:

```
WITH [Filter] AS (
    SELECT *
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [id_unit] ORDER BY [id_measure_type] DESC) [Rank]
      FROM @Table
     WHERE [measure] > 0
)
SELECT [id_unit], SUM([measure])
  FROM [Filter]
 WHERE [Rank] = 1
   AND [id_unit] IN (252, 107)
   AND [dateBid] BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
 GROUP BY [id_unit];
```

View of output prior to SUM():

```
WITH [Filter] AS (
    SELECT *
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [id_unit] ORDER BY [id_measure_type] DESC) [Rank]
      FROM @Table
     WHERE [measure] > 0
)
SELECT *
  FROM [Filter]
 WHERE [Rank] = 1
   AND [id_unit] IN (252, 107)
   AND [dateBid] BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

**EDIT (Hourly):**
I don't know if you have more data in the table, with the above sample the sum will only (as far as I can tell) only SUM() one row anyway, but it still works so I'll leave it in.

```
WITH [Filter] AS (
    SELECT *
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [id_unit], [Hour] ORDER BY [id_measure_type] DESC) [Rank]
      FROM @Table
     WHERE [measure] > 0
)
SELECT [id_unit], [Hour], SUM([measure])
  FROM [Filter]
 WHERE [Rank] = 1
   AND [id_unit] IN (252, 107)
   AND [dateBid] BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
 GROUP BY [id_unit], [Hour];
```

Comment: Is not working when there are more than one different hour. It gets only one hour for each unit, instead of summing every hour with the best type of measure =/

Comment: You'll have to add hour in the PARTITION BY if you want a Rank = 1 for each possible HOUR

Comment: What if the measure type order is not simply descending and is (from best to worse): `6`, `1`, `4`?

Comment: Put CASE around it in the ORDER BY, for example "DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [id_unit], [Hour] ORDER BY CASE [id_measure_type] WHEN 6 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 4 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END ASC) [Rank]" I suppose (unless you have a priority table you can join in of course).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how some of your columns are relevant, given that every sample row you've provided has the same values, and no `measure` is 0, but I think what you want is along these lines:

```
;With Priorities as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY id_unit,dateBid,hour
         ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN COALESCE(measure,0) > 0 THEN id_measure_type
             else -1 END desc) as priority
    from @t
)
select id_unit,SUM(measure)
from Priorities
where priority = 1
group by id_unit
```

Assuming that no `id_measure_type` is less than 0, and no `measure` is less than 0 - these can be adapted if those are requirements.

(I've added a `COALESCE`, on the assumption that your "empty or 0" requirement is actually talking about `NULL`s and 0s)

Comment: Well, my intention was that on the second unit there is no measure of type 6, but probably is not very clear. There are not going to be `NULL` values, only 0 values or missing values. My bad, edit my question for clarification.